# Marketing Automation Service Fail to Start

Tags: xconnect, marketing-automation

I am using Sitecore 10.2 and I am getting the below error:

[image]

[image]

I verified below things:

- License is correct.
- Thumbprint is correct.
- Certificate has IIS_IUSRS permission.
- .Net framework 4.8 has been installed
- xConnect is working

Comment: Are you using custom models? If so have you deployed the custom models to the MA engine? Are you using custo Also, you say XConnect is working, but is collectoin instance definitely exception free?

Comment: Yes I am using custom model

Comment: Please add the stack trace to the question as text and not an image. Give the SEO something to work with. Also, will help to include the entire stack tracre.

Comment: Try to go to marketing automation folder and run maengine.exe from cmd or powershell, then paste full stack trace here. This is running on .Net Core 3.1, not .Net 4.8.

Comment: @Kamil I can not see any error while running maengine.exe

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact you are using custom model and also that the last two calls in the stack trace seem model related:

- CurrentModel()
- CheckInitialized()

My suggestion is to check custom model is deployed correctly, as per this article: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-platform/deploy-a-custom-model.html

Specific reference to:

> **Deploy the model to the Marketing Automation Engine**

Comment: I tried this but same error is coming